# How to password protect email sending in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-client, microsoft-office-2013

I am using Outlook 2013 desktop application and sometimes the Outlook 2013 WebApp.

I want to password protect the email sending option so that if anyone tries to send an email using my email account, a password will be prompted to verify whether it's me.

I have tried changing the Mail settings by going to 
Control Panel > Mail > E-Mail Accounts > Double click on the account name > More Settings > Security > 
And ticked the Always prompt for logon credentials.
But it doesn't seem to work.

How can i set outlook settings to prompt a password when sending an email?
Is this a possible thing to do with Outlook 2013?

Comment: Just configure OUtlook NOT to safe your password.  By doing this you will have to enter your information each time you want to send and recieve email.

Comment: Lock your computer when you're away from the keyboard.

Comment: @Ramhound : Could you please tell me how to configure outlook to not to save the password.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 : I do always lock the computer but i need extra security in case if i forget to do so. :)

Answer (score 1):

go to the properties of your account, click **more settings**
on the **tab** *outgoing server* select *my outgoing server requires authentication*
select *Log on using*
enter your username but no password
leave *remember username* unchecked